# TAGs for all the resources for multiple Subscription with PowerShell output to csv

Tags: azure, powershell, csv

I am new to PowerShell and trying to get the tags for all the resources in multiple Azure subscriptions and send the output in the csv file. Below is the script, it is writing output on the screen but not in the csv file.  Could anyone correct me, to export all data to csv file. Appreciate your help.

```
SubscriptionIds = Get-Content -Path "path for SubscriptionID.txt"  
Foreach($SubscriptionId in $SubscriptionIds)
{
Try{$null = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId}
catch [Exception] {write-host ("Error occured: " + $($_.Exception.Message)) -ForegroundColor Red;Exit}
Write-Host "Azure Login Session successful" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black

# Initialise output array
$Output = @()

# Collect all the groups from the current subscription
$ResourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup 
foreach ($ResourceGroup in $ResourceGroups) {
    Write-Host "Resource Group =$($ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName)"
    $resourceNames= Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName
        $tags=Get-AzTag -ResourceId $ResourceGroup.ResourceId
        foreach($key in $tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Keys)
        {
        Write-Host "`t ResourceGroup = $($ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName) `t TagKey= $($key) `t Value = $($tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Item($($key)))"
        }
    foreach($res in $resourceNames)
    {
        Write-Host "ResourceName = $($res.Name)"
        $tags=Get-AzTag -ResourceId $res.ResourceId
        foreach($key in $tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Keys)
        {
        Write-Host "`t `t ResourceGroup = $($ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName) `t ResourceName = $($res.Name) `t TagKey= $($key) `t Value = $($tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Item($($key)))"
        }
    }
}
# Sent the final output to CSV
$Output | Export-Csv -Path test.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Append -Encoding UTF8 -Force 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not adding the output you are printing with the `Write-Host` cmdlet to the `$output` array:

```
SubscriptionIds = Get-Content -Path "path for SubscriptionID.txt"  
Foreach ($SubscriptionId in $SubscriptionIds) {
    Try { $null = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId }
    catch [Exception] { write-host ("Error occured: " + $($_.Exception.Message)) -ForegroundColor Red; Exit }
    Write-Host "Azure Login Session successful" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black

    # Initialise output array
    $Output = @()

    # Collect all the groups from the current subscription
    $ResourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup 
    foreach ($ResourceGroup in $ResourceGroups) {
        Write-Host "Resource Group =$($ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName)"
        $resourceNames = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName
        $tags = Get-AzTag -ResourceId $ResourceGroup.ResourceId
        foreach ($key in $tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Keys) {
            $Output += "`t ResourceGroup = $($ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName) `t TagKey= $($key) `t Value = $($tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Item($($key)))"
            Write-Host "`t ResourceGroup = $($ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName) `t TagKey= $($key) `t Value = $($tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Item($($key)))"
        }
        foreach ($res in $resourceNames) {
            Write-Host "ResourceName = $($res.Name)"
            $tags = Get-AzTag -ResourceId $res.ResourceId
            foreach ($key in $tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Keys) {
                $Output += "`t ResourceGroup = $($ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName) `t TagKey= $($key) `t Value = $($tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Item($($key)))"
                Write-Host "`t `t ResourceGroup = $($ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName) `t ResourceName = $($res.Name) `t TagKey= $($key) `t Value = $($tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Item($($key)))"
            }
        }
    }
    # Sent the final output to CSV
    $Output | Export-Csv -Path test.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Append -Encoding UTF8 -Force 
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you. When I updated the query as per your suggestions, i am getting this below results in the csv file, but not the tags .
Length
66
60
70
69
81
74
69
69
60
103
103
102
94
117
115
100

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$Output = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$ResourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup 
    foreach ($ResourceGroup in $ResourceGroups) {
        Write-Host "Resource Group =$($ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName)"
        $resourceNames = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName
        $tags = Get-AzTag -ResourceId $ResourceGroup.ResourceId
        foreach ($key in $tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Keys) {
            $csvObject = New-Object PSObject
            Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "ResourceGroup" -value $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName
            Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "ResourceName" -value ''
            Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "TagKey" -value $key
            Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Value" -value $tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Item($($key))
            $Output.Add($csvObject)

            #$Output += "`t ResourceGroup = $($ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName) `t TagKey= $($key) `t Value = $($tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Item($($key)))"
            Write-Host "`t ResourceGroup = $($ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName) `t TagKey= $($key) `t Value = $($tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Item($($key)))"
        }
        foreach ($res in $resourceNames) {
            Write-Host "ResourceName = $($res.Name)"
            $tags = Get-AzTag -ResourceId $res.ResourceId
            foreach ($key in $tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Keys) {
                $csvObject = New-Object PSObject
                Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "ResourceGroup" -value $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName
                Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "ResourceName" -value $res.Name
                Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "TagKey" -value $key
                Add-Member -inputObject $csvObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "Value" -value $tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Item($($key))               
                $Output.Add($csvObject)

                #$Output += "`t ResourceGroup = $($ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName) `t TagKey= $($key) `t Value = $($tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Item($($key)))"
                Write-Host "`t `t ResourceGroup = $($ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName) `t ResourceName = $($res.Name) `t TagKey= $($key) `t Value = $($tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Item($($key)))"
            }
        }
    }


$Output | Export-Csv -Path test.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Append -Encoding UTF8 -Force
```